# False Rejection Rate Vs. False Positive Rate

Tags: voice-recognition, verification, face-recognition, biometrics, false-positive

Is the FRR similar to FPR ? Then, if it is similar, why does different definitions for each of them are available?

FRR=(Number of genuine claims)/(Number of genuine accesses)×100%

FPR= (number of false positives) / (number of false positives + number of true negatives)

Comment: I think you are asking in the wrong place. Your question has nothing to do with programming. It would probably fit in DataScience, rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: could you pls give me the link for DataScience ?

Comment: you can easily find it in the upper left corner of this very page. However, it's datascience.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I think you work in biometrics filed, is not it? 
I was confused about that and find out it.
I found that FRR and FPR are not same, however FRR is equal to FNR, in biometrics. Because in biometric authentication system, identification is positive work, so when you speak about FRR means you speak about wrong action. please check following link:

http://books.google.de/books?id=B0Lwc6ZEQhcC&pg=PA876&lpg=PA876&dq=false+rejection+rate+and+false+positive+rate+same?&source=bl&ots=_-jJNxLklk&sig=gE_Io_5OqnEGUuaq3ITAUiuhQRI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2iysU8SvHenE4gSgmICgDw&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=false%20rejection%20rate%20and%20false%20positive%20rate%20same%3F&f=false

kheyli khoshhal misham agar dar in zamineh chizi fahmidi be man ham etelaa bedi.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! Could you please rework your answer ? Right now, it's hard to understand what you're saying (especially at the end :) ). Also, It would be nice to present the link using markdown (just on top of the text area).